# From two hashes obtain another with keys non repeated in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two hashes in ruby and I want compare both and then create another with the keys and values of non repeated keys.

```
A = {"name1" => 123, "name2" => 321, "name3" => 412 }
B = {"name1" => 412, "name2" => 412, "name4" => 444}
```

I want compare B with A, and obtain a new hash with the keys and values of the keys that are not present in A.

```
C = {"name4" => 444}
```

Could you help me please? 
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Hash#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-select) or [`Hash#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject) without the bang:

```
C = B.select { |k, _| !A[k] }
#=> {"name4"=>444}
B.reject { |k, _| A[k] }
#=> {"name4"=>444}
```

If your hash contains boolean values, use `nil?` method (`A[k].nil?`) or `Hash#has_key?` (`A.has_key?`).

Also you can use  [`Hash#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) method:

```
C = B.delete_if { |k, v| A.has_key?(k) }
#=> {"name4"=>444}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Finally, note that `delete_if` mutates `B`.